# Array of structures passed in to a function, dereferencing difference between -> and *

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I have a structure, a pointer of this structure malloced in main () so I can make a dynamic array of structures and I want to fill up the array using this function:

```
void LoadData ( STRUCTURE ** str ){
```

So my question is why my program throws Segmentation fault when I use this notion:

```
           scanf( " %d", &str[i]->len )
```

And everything works just fine when I use this one:

```
           scanf( " %d", &(*str)[i].len )
```

I thought that (*str).len is equivalent to str->len. 
Also both works for 1st element of the array. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(*str).len` is equivalent to `str->len` when `str` is a pointer to a structure. For a more comprehensive answer, you'll need to post a [mcve].

Comment: So because ** str is a pointer to pointer on structure I can't use ->, right  ?

Comment: Sorry, that's not right. See [mcve] for details.

Comment: `str[i]->len` means `str[i][0].len`, and `(*str)[i].len` means `str[0][i].len`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you describe it, in your `LoadData()` function, `str` is a pointer to a scalar, which scalar happens to be another pointer.  `str[i]` therefore produces an out-of-bounds array access when `i` is different from 0, because for this purpose, a scalar is equivalent to a single-element array.

On the other hand, `*str`, another pointer, points to the first element of an array.  Supposing that that array contains `n` elements, therefore, the expression `(*str)[i]` accesses a valid array element (of type `STRUCTURE`) for any `i` between 0 and `n - 1`, inclusive.  Because that designates a `STRUCTURE`, not a `STRUCTURE *`, you must access its members via the `.` operator, rather than via `->`.

To see more clearly that your two expressions are different, let's transform them according to the identities `a[b] == *((a) + (b))` and `p->x == (*p).x`.  On one hand we have

```
&str[i]->len == &(str[i]->len)
             == &((*str[i]).len)
             == &((**(str + i)).len)
```

whereas on the other we have

```
&(*str)[i].len == &(((*str)[i])).len)
               == &((*(*str + i)).len)
```

.  Observe that `**(str + i)` is not equivalent to `*(*str + i)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that (*str).len is equivalent to str->len (for a structure pointer str).  However, array indexing and member access both have the same precedence and are left-associative.  As a result, your first example is interpreted as

```
scanf( " %d", &((str[i])->len) )
```

whereas your second example is interpreted as

```
scanf( " %d", &(((*str)[i]).len) )
```

Using concrete indexes for everything, the first version is writing to str[i][0].len, whereas the second is writing to str[0][i].len.